# Net/IMAP SSL error, 2.1.5 and 2.2.1, but 2.1.0 and 2.1.2 works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, imap

I have the problem that my development machine does not want to connect to my IMAP accounts any more. I know I must have changed something, but cannot think of anything relevant. But what I found is, that with ruby 2.1.0 and 2.1.2 my application works, but with 2.1.5 and 2.2.1 [edit: 2.2.2 failing, too] it does not work.

So I started debugging and extracted the parts that actually connect and throw the SSL error. The shortened script is the following:

```
require 'net/imap'

@imap = nil

begin
  @imap = Net::IMAP.new("mail.example.com", {port: 143})
  @imap.starttls({}, true)
  @imap.login("username", "password")
rescue => e
  puts e
end
```

The result with 2.0.0 and 2.1.2 is empty, so it worked. But with 2.1.5 and 2.2.1 [edit: and 2.2.2] I get the following error:

> SSL_write: certificate verify failed

Of course I immediately checked the server's keychain, but it seems okay. It results in

> Verify return code: 0 (ok)

though it has the line

> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

but I read that this error is "normal". I cannot explain this error, as I included the certificates correctly with my dovecot server, but when searching the web it looks like everyone else is getting this line with most certificates, too, and it works. Also, like mentioned before, the verify return code is 0, so everything should work.

Do you have an idea if this is a problem with the mentioned line or if it's a bug with newer ruby versions? I could not find any clear search results regarding this.

PS: I need to use starttls, "ssl: true" gives me an unknown protocol error, as I enabled tls only.

edit2: I re-checked again. On the production server, 2.1.5 works. Could it be a problem with CA certificates on the development server or something? But why do older versions work then and newer don't?

--- edit: output as requested ---

I changed my real domain to domain.com in the bin. The host is a sub domain and the certificate a subdomain wildcard certificate from RapidSSL (*.domain.com).

http://pastebin.com/9BGK4w1w

Comment: *"Do you have an idea if this is a problem with the mentioned line or if it's a bug with newer ruby versions?"* - Ruby has been tightening some of their security related code recently. I'm just guessing, but I'd venture to say the code in the past was probably more questionable...

Comment: ***`Net::IMAP.new("mail.example.com", {port: 143})`*** - we need to know more about the host's configuration. Please post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: I added it … thanks in advance :-) Had to adjust the command a bit, as I got a "wrong version" error with this exact line.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it by reinstalling OS X. For some reason it was a problem with my system, though I triple-checked everything from OpenSSL to rvm, Ruby, system-wide installed authority certificates and so on.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: sometimes ruby gems seems to be annoying